# Can we use single google map api key for both xamarin form android and xamarin form ios?

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms

I have rendered google map in xamarin form iso but it is not working in android. I don't know if I am doing something wrong in my android setup or not.

My question is: can we use single google map api key in both application?

In google console I see:

```
Application restrictions specify which web sites, IP addresses, or apps 
can use this key. You can set one restriction type per key.
```

Where i can choose only one option among http, ip, android and ios.

If tutorial link for google map in xamarinform would also be appreciated. I am using googlemaps nuget package.

Answer (score 1):

According to Google, you should be using a different API key for Android and iOS for a better understanding I would suggest you read [this document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key).

In your case, I would recommend you create an API key for your iOS app and another client API key for your Android app (different than the iOS one).

On your [Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) select create a new API key, you can see that Google gives you different choices: server key, browser key, iOS key, Android key, etc. Each different key serves different purposes and should be limited to the corresponding platform only (e.g.: do not put a server key in a client app like an iOS app, and vice versa).

As of an example, you can check [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-google-maps-api/) out.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes. You can use the same Google map api key in both application (Android/iOS), just use [Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps](https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps) NuGet

You can found a tutorial for GoogleMaps in Xamarin Forms in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61982084/5869384).